# How can I interact with rawdata in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to capture rawdata from touchscreen only. I get tons of them when checking for `HID`. And also according to the [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645581(v=vs.85).aspx), I should only receive 0,1 and 2. Why did I receive 3? The main goal is to capture and print out all the coords from touchscreen. All the coords means there might be multiple touches.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
internal static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
internal static extern uint GetRawInputData(IntPtr hRawInput, uint uiCommand, 
    IntPtr pData, ref uint pcbSize, uint cbSizeHeader);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
internal static extern bool RegisterRawInputDevices(RAWINPUTDEVICE[] pRawInputDevice, 
    uint uiNumDevices, uint cbSize);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
internal static extern uint GetRawInputDeviceList(IntPtr pRawInputDeviceList, 
    ref uint uiNumDevices, uint cbSize);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
internal static extern uint GetRawInputDeviceInfo(IntPtr hDevice, uint uiCommand, 
    IntPtr pData, ref uint pcbSize);

internal const int RIM_TYPEHID = 2;

internal const uint RIDI_DEVICENAME = 0x20000007;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    uint deviceCount = 0;
    int dwSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST));

    if (GetRawInputDeviceList(IntPtr.Zero, ref deviceCount, (uint)dwSize) == 0)
    {
        IntPtr pRawInputDeviceList = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)(dwSize * deviceCount));
        GetRawInputDeviceList(pRawInputDeviceList, ref deviceCount, (uint)dwSize);

        for (int i = 0; i < deviceCount; i++)
        {
            // ***here! how can I know which one is from touchscreen?***
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Error!");
    }
}
```

Comment: both, but i would prefer to know how to get all the 'touch' coords (not mouse)

Comment: @YvetteColomb just edited. thanks